# How to "collapse" a view's height with an animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to make disappearing a simple View sliding behind another one, I've tried like any kind of animation but none of them succeded..

This is what I've tried by far:

```
public void slideToTop(View view){
        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-view.getHeight());
        animate.setDuration(1000);
        view.startAnimation(animate);
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

with and without a ReverseInterpolator

```
public class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator {
        public float getInterpolation(float paramFloat) {
            return Math.abs(paramFloat -1f);
        }
    }
```

or with Scaling

```
public void scaling(View view) {
        ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0,0,1,1.5f);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

or with the new api

```
editView.animate().translationY(-editView.getHeight()).withLayer();
```

Any help on how to achieve this?

My layout is something like:

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
      <TextView/>
      <View/> <!-- This should "disappear" sliding up behind the other one -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- more of the previous -->
    <LinearLayout>
      <TextView/>
      <View/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the effect that View B disappears behind view A you need to draw B before A:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <ViewB />
   <ViewA above="ViewB"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then move ViewB around. I have done the same with the following code, that will move viewToMove up by it's own height:

```
public void collapse() {
        View viewToMove= mainView.findViewById(R.id.viewToMove);
        int pixelsToMove= viewToMove.getHeight() * -1;
        slots.animate().yBy(pixelsToMove).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MS);
    }
```

Take care when you call `getHeight()` you might need a `ViewTreeObserver` to get the correct value, because most times before the view is drawn `getHeight()` will just return 0

Comment: Almost there (I guess). I'm creating the layout programmatically. Do you know how can I set the ABOVE? I did `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, editView.getId());` but it's not working. : /

Comment: Ok, I've still some problems but your animation is correct. Thanks. : )